# How to get layers name added to OpenLayers map v6.14.1?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, layers

I'm trying to get name of layers added to OpenLayers v6.14.1, I found some methods but they were very old for instance: "map.layers" and one other method I found was :

```
let addLayers = map.getLayers();
let length =  addLayers.getLength();
for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
   console.log('layers added already name = ', map.getLayers().item(i).get('name'))
}
```

but when I used above method I got "undefined" message.

I'm going to know how I can get name of layers added to Openlayers map v6.14.1?

my layers are WMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layers in OL do not have names by default, but you can give layer a name by setting some custom layer property, like for example using custom option `name: 'My layer name'`. Then your code above will work.

Example of such a code would be:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
  style: style,
  name: 'My layer name'
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, i got it, but I confused a little, if they have not name why I can see their name in getLayers().item(i).get('source') like this tiger:topp part one is datastore name (in GeoServer) second part is layer name

Comment: With `getLayers().item(i).get('source')` you get source object of your layer, and what you see is value of `params` option attribute `LAYERS: "topp:states"` when defining layer source.